# Substring before numeric

Tags: java, android, string

I have :

```
String word = "It cost me 500 box
```

What I want to do is to display this sentence like this :

```
It cost me

500 box
```

I need a general methode, not only for this example. 
Can you helpe me please ?

Comment: Use the Java regex classes.

Comment: You can use regular expressions for this. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)'s a link to get you started.

Comment: Are this strings in the same pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there are anymore inbuilt functions that I know of, but one way of doing this would be:

```
void match(String string) {
    int numIndex = -1;
    int charIndex = 0;

    if (string.length() > 0) {  
        while (numIndex == -1 && charIndex < string.length()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(charIndex)))
                numIndex = charIndex;
            charIndex++;
        }
    }

    if (numIndex != -1) {
        System.out.println(string.substring(0, numIndex));
        System.out.println(string.substring(numIndex));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested you can use regular expression to do this job below is a code snippet that can do the trick for you:

```
    String word = "It cost me 500 box";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.* )([0-9].*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @BlidTounsi if it helped you , kindly accept as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not the optimum way but an easy one:

On top of your Activity:

```
String finalText="";
public static boolean isNumber(String string)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(string);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException e)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

In your code:

```
String word = "It cost me 500 box";
        for (int i=0 ; i<word.length() ; i++){
            String a = Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
            if (isNumber(a)){
                finalText+="\n";
                for (int j=i ; j<word.length() ; j++){
                    String b = Character.toString(word.charAt(j));
                    finalText+=b;
                }
                i = word.length();
            }
            else{
                finalText+=a;
            }
        }
        textView.setText(finalText);
```